# C++ how to bind lambda with variadic and references

Tags: c++17

I use a library when many classes are written with a init() method returning boolean. I have read that it allow to return an error code. The signature have nothing common (the parameters can be anything) but the return type is almost always bool and the function name is always the same, init. The arguments can be anything.

Example:

```cpp
class Handle {
  Handle(const Handle&) = delete;
};

class BigResource {
  BigResource(const BigResource&) = delete;
};

class A {
  bool init(int, const BigResource&);
};

class B {
  bool init(unsigned int, unsigned int, Handle&);
};

class D {
  bool init();
}

class E {
  bool init(const std::string&, const std::string&);
}

/* ... All classes are also not copyable */
```

The First Question is, that i would like to use these classes with container. A condition is that I assume that all call to init() should return true, not that they always return true but the program fails if any initialization does not work (unrecoverable error, like a bad malloc or asset not found). I tried to wrap all theses classes into another one that handle the initialization automatically, but this is not possible since the conversion operator does not work because there classes are not copyable.

So I managed to use std::generate to initialize the STL containers with a call to init() for each element. Now is the current problem: I would like to have a generic Generator class, or a functor, for initializing all the elements with the same argument that can handle any type respecting the reference arguments ? `std::bind` pass by values, and I don't know if it's possible to use somethings like `std::ref` with a variadic, with some arguments are passed by value and some by reference.

What I tried to do:

```cpp
    /**
     * Functor to achieve the same effect but with a functor and stored arguments
     */
    template<typename T> struct Creator
    {
        template<typename... Args>
        Creator(Args&&... createArgs)
        {
            //m_callCreate = std::bind(create<T, Args...>, std::placeholders::_1, std::forward<Args>(createArgs)...); First test

            m_callCreate = [&](T &obj) {
                obj.init(std::forward<Args>(createArgs)...);
            };
        }

        void operator()(T& t) {
            m_callCreate(t);
        }

    private:
        std::function<void(T&)> m_callCreate;
    };
```

Does that work ? I feel like the lambda capture is resulting in a dangling reference. I tried also other possibilities (store a tuple, or a std::bind wrapped in a std::function that look like to wrap easely all arguments, but I don't know which method is better and even if it is not UB.)
I don't understand deeply this functions and all possible behaviors, but in brief I would like to have the same behavior as if the init method was called directly, that is:

- when a parameter is a reference, use the reference (the referenced object should live until the last call of operator())
- when a parameter is a value, and I feel like here is the real problem, capture by value, like an `int` (the original object can be freed at the end of the constructor)

Desired behavior:

```cpp
// This code may be not possible

Handle handle;
std::vector<B> v(10, {1920, 1080, handle});


// Or at least:

Handle handle;
Generator<B> generator(1920, 1080, handle);
std::vector<B> v(10);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), generator);
```

Comment: So `Handle` should be copied because it is non-const ? But it has deleted copy constructor ?

Comment: No the const was not adequate, it should not be copied because it's a reference (finally the const has no impact)

Comment: Something [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/992dd17844143b3f)

Comment: I'm confused after your last edit. Why won't you use `std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&] { return B(1920, 1080, handle); });`

Comment: No all classes (BigResource, Handle, A, B, etc...) has no copy constructor and move constructor. I can not modify it and it was written in C++03, before move semantics

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to wrap all theses classes into another one that handle the initialization automatically, but this is not possible since the conversion operator does not work because there classes are not copyable.

Two things you could try in this respect:

1. Inherit from these classes instead of holding them as a member in a wrapper class:

   ```
   class BigResource;
   class A;
   class MyA : A {
       A wrapped;
   public:
       MyA() : wrapped() {
           auto result = wrapped.init();
           if (not result) { throw std::logic_error("Failed initializing A"); }
       }
       // more constructors
       // etc. etc
   }
   ```
2. Use move constructors instead of copy constructors on `BigResource` and `Handle`